# Python ввод в консоль(Читать кат)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Сейчас будет трудно, мне надо симулировать ввод в консоль(CMD), а точнее команду STOP. И... у меня даже идей нет(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

библиотека pykeyboard поможет.
Ставится pip install PyUserInput

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
k = PyKeyboard()
k.type_string('STOP')
k.tap_key(k.enter_key)
```

Comment: А можно как-то заставить его сменить активное окно?